# Custom template tag don't work as expected (django)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My custom template tag is called `change_page` and should change `page=x` in the url without changing anything else in the url. (That means anything in the url, before and behind the `?`.

That's the template code part: (it works with the standard django paginator)

```
 {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <a href="{{ request.path }}?{% change_page current=request.GET.urlencode page=page_obj.previous_page_number %}" class="left_sharp">Zurück</a>
     {% else %}
        <a tabindex="2" href="" class="noteditable">Zurück</a>
     {% endif %}

     <div class="screen_only">
     {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
      {% ifequal page_obj.number i %}
        <a href="" tabindex="2" class="noteditable">{{ i }}</a>
      {% else %}
        <a href="{{ request.path }}?{% change_page current=request.GET.urlencode page=i %}">{{ i }}</a>
      {% endifequal %}
     {% endfor %}
     </div>

     {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <a href="{{ request.path }}?{% change_page current=request.GET.urlencode page=page_obj.next_page_number %}" class="right_sharp">Weiter</a>
     {% else %}
        <a href="" tabindex="2" class="noteditable">Weiter</a>
     {% endif %}
    </nav>
    {% endif %}
```

The code of the template tag `change_page`:

```
@register.simple_tag
def change_page(current="", page=""):
    args = current.split('&')       
    all=''

    for arg in args:
        all += re.sub(r'page=[0-9]+', 'page='+str(page), arg) + '&'

    all = all[:-1]

    return all
```

It doesn't work.
It allways returns an empty string. What did I wrong?

Comment: Try removing the `.urlencode`. In fact, [`urlencode`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode) it's a Django built-in template filter. See what it does.

Comment: `.urlencode` is right. [`request.GET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET") returns a QueryDict, which is similar to a immutable dictionary. [`request.GET.urlencode`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.urlencode) returns the part of the url after the question mark. (An url looks like this: `myurl/?encodedquerydict` that can look like this: `example.com/example/directoy/?key=value&extravar`.)

Answer (score 0):

It didn't worked because I did nothing when there was no page argument in `request.GET.urlencode`.

I added this code in the beginning of the method, and now it works fine unless it adds a `=` to arguments which are only keys, and have no values.

```
if current == "":
        return 'page='+str(page)

    if not re.compile('page=[0-9]+').match(current):
        return current + '&page=' + str(page)
```